# How to generate pdf using TeXstudio without getting an error when opening?

Tags: texstudio

I open TeXstudio, I press `File->New from template-> Article->Ok` then I use the double green arrow to compile (the play button didn't work either) and view the pdf. After that I want to save that pdf so I use `File-> Save As...` and then I save it as a pdf file but I can't open it using Adobe reader or even Sumatra Pdf reader.

If someone can tell me step-by-step the instructions that I have to follow I would appreciate it.

**EDIT:** I got it to work. In TeXstudio when saving I used `Save As->All files` then I clicked the `Build&View` button and then the play button.

Comment: Don't use save as.  This is not necessary, the pdf is already there (as you can view it).  Look in the  folder  of your tex-file.

Comment: When you compile a `tex` file the `pdf` file is created at the same folder. So you don't need to save it again. If you wish you can open the `pdf` with an external viewer instead of the embedded one.

Comment: "Save as" is for the *source* file, not the generated output file. If you save the source file as `.pdf` file and then generate the `.pdf` file, then the source file will very likely be destroyed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.