# TeXstudio generates "plain text" when using Build&View (Debian+XFCE)

Tags: theorems, texstudio

I saw [this closed question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253410/how-to-generate-pdf-using-texstudio-without-getting-an-error-when-opening) and I'm experienceing something similar: for .tex documents, when I press the f5 key, which triggers the macro "Build and view", I get an output .pdf file that is treated by Thunar as a "plain text" file; I doulbe-click on it and the text editor is executed. I use the embedded pdf viewer in TeXstudio.

Running pdflatex on a terminal or using another editor, the problem doesn't occur; even on TeXstudio, if I only use the Build macro and then the view command, I get a proper .pdf file.

I even ran the Build > View on the following file:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

The Build > View command produced a proper PDF from the above.

Any ideas on how to know what is going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was an environment whose call word was `rem` (I used it to define a Remark 'theorem': `\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}`). I just renamed it and now running Build&View produces a true PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

`F5` is the default shortcut for `Build & View`, check if this is your current shortcut in Options/Configure TeXstudio.../Shortcuts/Menus/Tools.

`Build & View` is defined in Options/Configure TeXstudio.../Build/Build & View. Please check the value of this. The default value is `txs:///compile | txs:///view`. If this is different, please set it back to that.

`txs:///compile` is defined just below `Build & View`, please check that the value is `txs:///pdflatex`

`txs:///pdflatex` is defined in Options/Configure TeXstudio.../Commands/PdfLaTeX and the default value is `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. If this is different, please set it back to that.

If this does not solve, could you describe some more the "plain-text .pdf file" contents?

Comment: The configuration is as you describe it. I cannot tell you about the contents of the file because when trying to open it (on Mousepad, in my case) I get a window with the error "The document was not UTF-8 valid"; changing the encoding doesn't allow me to open it either. However, in trying to get into the contents, I typed on terminal `cat output.pdf > output2.pdf` (just as an example) and this produced a proper PDF file. Again, the faulted PDF is produced only when I run `Build & View`.

Comment: I can't understand how this could happen, there seems to be a problem with TeXstudio as one button works and the other doesn't and there seems to be a problem with your Debian deciding that two seemingly identical (`cat` just identically copies the content from one file to the other, no modification of the content, just the creation date, the permissions and other non-important things will be different) files should be opened in two different ways. Can you share the faulty pdf?

Comment: I was about to share the file but I started experimenting; I had defined a 'theorem' for Remarks, and I named it `rem`; it was this that was causing trouble; I just renamed it and everything works fine! Apparently \rem is some sort of internal command for TeXstudio: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/09d48286/
Thanks for the interest! :)

Comment: This is weird... Maybe it's a TeXstudio bug or something like that. If you can provide a MWE with this behaviour it would be interesting. Just adding that newtheorem in a document of mine is not enough for reproducing the weird behaviour.

Comment: What version of TeXstudio do you use?  Mine is 2.12.14 from the Debian testing repos.

Comment: Mine is also 2.12.14, from Arch repos

Comment: Then I don't know what caused it. Any ideas on how to find out?

Comment: Create a Minimal Non-Working Example so we can test :)

Comment: Adding `\newtheorem{rem}{foo}` to the example I used in the OP is a MNWE, but apparently only on my installation.